# Get cxf-codegen-plugin to generate the Holder classes

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm upgrading a `web-service` client that was previously using `axis` to now use `CXF`. Note that the `web-service` belongs to a 3rd party, so I have no access to modify the `wsdl` myself.

```
<message name="doSomethingRequest">
  <part name="parameters" element="doSomething" />
</message>

<message name="doSomethingResponse">
  <part name="parameters" element="doSomethingResponse" />
</message>

<portType name="myServicePortType">
  <operation name="doSomething">
    <input message="doSomethingRequest" />
    <output message="doSomethingResponse" />
  </operation>
</portType>
```

As you can see, with the way, the `message`s and `operation`s are documented in the `WSDL`, a binding style of `WRAPPED` is chosen when the `wsdl2java` is invoked thru the `cxf-codegen-plugin`, which is fine. My old `*PortType` class, generated thru `axistools-maven-plugin` / `wsdl2java` also had all the methods in the `WRAPPED` style with `Holder` classes as parameter types and without a return type.

But my problem is, when I was previously using the `axistools-maven-plugin` to generate the `java` classes, all my `*Holder` classes were also generated automatically to match the `*PortType` interface needs. But with the `cx-codegen-plugin`, only the `*PortType` interface reflects the `WRAPPED` style requiring `Holder` types for the `OUT` parameters; I don't see the `*Holder` classes generated as part of the `wsdl2java`!

Any way I can get the `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate the `*Holder` classes as part of `wsdl2java` without writing them myself? I don't want to switch to the `BARE` binding style since that would mean a lot of refactoring. I can't modify the `WSDL` either like I had mentioned earlier.

I use `v3.0.2` of `cxf-codegen-plugin` and `JAXB` databinding fwiw.

```
@RequestWrapper(localName = "doSomething", targetNamespace = "...", className = "...DoSomething")
@WebMethod(action = "urn:#doSomething")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "doSomethingResponse", targetNamespace = "...", className = "...DoSomethingResponse")
public void doSomething(
  @WebParam(name = "requestParam1", targetNamespace = "...")
  java.lang.String requestParam1,
  @WebParam(name = "requestParam2", targetNamespace = "...")
  java.lang.String requestParam2,

  // the below holders for SomeType1 and SomeType2, i.e the SomeType1Holder and SomeType2Holder, are not auto-generated as part of the wsdl2java

  @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "responseParam1", targetNamespace = "...")
  javax.xml.ws.Holder<SomeType1> responseParam1,
  @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "responseParam2", targetNamespace = "...")
  javax.xml.ws.Holder<SomeType2> responseParam2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate `Holder` class; it's part of JAX-WS.

You may want to check JDK version used by your compiler. As far as I know JAX-WS was included in Java SE in version 6 so if your compiler is using Java SE 5 - that might be your problem.